# Update field using custom controller gets empty string

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I have a custom controller on a custom object book__c:

```
    public class fetchingController {

    public String newTitle;
    public list<Book__c>  bookList {get;set;}
    public Integer id  {get;set;}
    public Integer uid {get;set;}

    public String getNewTitle() {
        return newTitle;
    }

    public void setNewTitle(String newT) {
        newTitle = newT;
    }

    public fetchingController(){
           bookList = [Select Id , Name, author__c, title__c, price__c from Book__c];
    }


   // Method to update the title Book Record 

   public PageReference updatebook() {
        String bookUid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uid');

        System.debug('Bookid = ' + bookUid + ', newTitle = ' + newTitle);
        Book__c book =[select Id  from Book__c where id = : bookUid];
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Controller2');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
   }
}
```

and the page is:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="fetchingController" id="pageId" >
<apex:form id="formId">
        <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlockId1" title="Books Available">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!bookList}" var="bk" id="pageBlockTableId">
                <apex:column headerValue="id">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!bk.id}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue=" Name">
                    <b>  {!bk.Name } </b> 
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Author">
                    {!bk.Author__c}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Title">
                    {!bk.Title__c} 
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Price">
                    {!bk.Price__c}
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="revisedTitle">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!newtitle}" id="inputtitle" />
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!updatebook}" value="Salva" >
                        <apex:param value="{!bk.id}" name="uid" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

What I want to do is to update the title book using that inputText.
The problem is that it always read a *null* string, but the program can see the right *Id* record.
I'm quite new to Apex, so what am I missing?

UPDATE:
If I have a look at the debug, I see that it prints a bookid that is valid, while newtitle is '' (empty).
[image]

Btw, I updated the code with the dml operation, which is update book.
So, it seems it doesn't get the string inserted.

Answer (score 2):

As you need to update the title only, so instead of the DML `insert` statement use `update` statement. So update your method as below.

```
 public PageReference updatebook() {
    String bookUid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uid');
    System.debug('Bookid = ' + bookUid + ', newTitle = ' + newTitle);
    Book__c book =[select Id, Title__c  from Book__c where id = : bookUid];
    book.Title__c = newTitle;

    //update the book object
    update book;

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Controller2');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Comment: I updated the question because it doesn't get the value of the string.

Comment: Ok, got it Try to replace "newTitle" with the "this.newTitle" in "getNewTitle", "setNewTitle" and "updatebook" methods.

Comment: I tried, but I still get the empty string

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the title field in your apex method such as

> ObjectReference.FieldApiName = Titlename;

and your DML operation to insert/update the record in the Db:

> insert ObjectReference;

Comment: I updated the question because it doesn't get the value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing assigning newTitle to books Title__c and  Update DML to update book.
update updateBook Method as below.

```
    public PageReference updatebook() {
            String bookUid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('uid');

            System.debug('Bookid = ' + bookUid + ', newTitle = ' + newTitle);
            Book__c book =[select Id, Title__c  from Book__c where id = : bookUid];
           book.Title__c = newTitle;
         update book;
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Controller2');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
   }
```

Comment: I updated the question because it doesn't get the value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the String newTitle with getter/setter in controller:

```
public String newTitle {get;set;}
```

Comment: Hi @Subhasis, I tried before with this method, but I didn't get the string anyway.